# Plotting multiple markers in a map ArcGIS Qt

Tags: c++, qt, arcgis

I have an application in which I am drawing transects on an ArcGIS map. I want to display a marker at all points on the transect. Currently, the marker is only displayed at the most recent clicked point. I want the marker to be displayed at all the clicked points. Most questions that I have seen involve QML.

This is the CPP file

```
#ifdef PCH_BUILD
#include "pch.hpp"
#endif // PCH_BUILD

#include "GeodesicOperations.h"

#include "Map.h"
#include "MapQuickView.h"
#include "GraphicsOverlay.h"
#include "Graphic.h"
#include "SimpleMarkerSymbol.h"
#include "SimpleLineSymbol.h"
#include "GeometryEngine.h"
#include "SpatialReference.h"
#include "PolylineBuilder.h"
#include "Point.h"
#include <QDebug>

using namespace Esri::ArcGISRuntime;

GeodesicOperations::GeodesicOperations(QQuickItem* parent /* = nullptr */):
  QQuickItem(parent)
{
}

void GeodesicOperations::init()
{
  // Register the map view for QML
  qmlRegisterType<MapQuickView>("Esri.Samples", 1, 0, "MapView");
  qmlRegisterType<GeodesicOperations>("Esri.Samples", 1, 0, "GeodesicOperationsSample");

}

void GeodesicOperations::componentComplete()
{
  QQuickItem::componentComplete();

  // find QML MapView component
  m_mapView = findChild<MapQuickView*>("mapView");

  // Create a map using the imagery basemap
  m_map = new Map(BasemapStyle::ArcGISImageryStandard, this);

  // Set map to map view
  m_mapView->setMap(m_map);

  // Create a GraphicsOverlay
   GraphicsOverlay* graphicsOverlay = new GraphicsOverlay(this);
   m_mapView->graphicsOverlays()->append(graphicsOverlay);

   // Create Graphic Symbols
   SimpleMarkerSymbol* markerSymbol = new SimpleMarkerSymbol(SimpleMarkerSymbolStyle::Circle, QColor("red"), 10.0f /*size*/, this);
   SimpleLineSymbol* pathSymbol = new SimpleLineSymbol(SimpleLineSymbolStyle::Dash, QColor("yellow"), 5.0f /*width*/, this);

   // Create source graphic
   const Point nycPoint(73.8021,15.4561, SpatialReference::wgs84());
   m_nycGraphic = new Graphic(nycPoint,markerSymbol, this);
   
   graphicsOverlay->graphics()->append(m_nycGraphic);

   // Create destination graphic
   m_destinationGraphic = new Graphic(this);
   m_destinationGraphic->setSymbol(markerSymbol);
   graphicsOverlay->graphics()->append(m_destinationGraphic);

   // Create path graphic
   m_pathGraphic = new Graphic(this);
   m_pathGraphic->setSymbol(pathSymbol);
   graphicsOverlay->graphics()->append(m_pathGraphic);

   PolylineBuilder* polylineBuilder=new PolylineBuilder(SpatialReference::wgs84(),this);
   
   // connect to mouse clicked signal
    connect(m_mapView, &MapQuickView::mouseClicked,  this, [ this, polylineBuilder](QMouseEvent& mouseEvent)
   
    {

      // re-project the point to match the NYC graphic
      const Point clickedPoint = m_mapView->screenToLocation(mouseEvent.x(), mouseEvent.y());
      const Point destination = GeometryEngine::project(clickedPoint, m_nycGraphic->geometry().spatialReference());

      // update the destination graphic

      m_destinationGraphic->setGeometry(destination);



      


       polylineBuilder->addPoint(destination);

       
       Polyline polyline = polylineBuilder->toPolyline();



      // densify the path as a geodesic curve and show it with the path graphic
      constexpr double maxSegmentLength = 1.0;
      const LinearUnit unitOfMeasurement(LinearUnitId::Kilometers);
      constexpr GeodeticCurveType curveType = GeodeticCurveType::NormalSection;



      const Geometry pathGeometry = GeometryEngine::densifyGeodetic(polyline, maxSegmentLength, unitOfMeasurement, curveType);

      // update the graphic
      m_pathGraphic->setGeometry(pathGeometry);

      // calculate the path's geodetic length
      m_distanceText = QString::number(GeometryEngine::lengthGeodetic(pathGeometry, unitOfMeasurement, curveType), 'f', 2);
      emit distanceTextChanged();
    });
  }



QString GeodesicOperations::distanceText() const
{
  return m_distanceText;
}
```

[Pic of the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gIdhs.jpg)